# How to filter the Form record source query?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-office

I'm creating a form that has a query as record source. I'm trying to build a filter option based on a Combo Box. When a value is selected in the Combo Box I want to show this filter on the form. So for example: if I select <500 then the table needs to show only the field with less then 500 records.

So the Form Record Source query needs to be updated. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the RecordSource of the form to:

```
Select Top 1000000 * From YourQuery
```

After selecting a value in the combobox, adjust the *RecordSource*:

```
Dim RecordSource As String
Dim Records As Long

RecordSource = "Select Top 1000000 * From YourQuery"
Records = Nz(Me!YourComboBox.Value, "1000000")

Me.RecordSource = Replace(RecordSource, "1000000", Records)
```